# supervisord process produces a lot of I/o problem

Tags: io

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ21X.jpg)

system info:
https://elinux.org/Jetson
ubuntu 20.04
docker + supervisor
jetpack 5.1.1

When the exception occurred, no other problems were found, the CPU/network and so on were checked, only supervisord had a lot of Io behavior, which puzzled me...
Has anyone come across this problem, or has it ever been solved?